# How to check if this deque is empty in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, deque

```
from collections import deque 
Q = deque()
```

How to check if this deque is empty? Is there any function like isEmpty() to check this? Can someone help? I looked for a function in the documentation but unable to find any?

Comment: you can use len(Q)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len

Comment: Do normal operations of list also works on it? like q[0] and q[-1]?

Comment: @RitikaGupta yes

Comment: @A.J.Uppal I checked it but it hasn't mentioned it is for "from collections import deque " this queue or general queue (list implementation)

Comment: @RitikaGupta I believe for `collections.deque` it works: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/lib_pypy/_collections.py

Comment: *Any* collection evaluates to false when empty. ``if Q:`` is totally sufficient to check whether it is not empty, and ``if not Q:`` to check whether it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of `Q` will be 0 if the input of deque() is empty:

```
from collections import deque
Q = deque()
assert len(Q) == 0
```

Comment: `__len__` simply invokes `len`, which is far more pythonic. `__len__` is a magic method.

Comment: yes, you are right, that's easier

Comment: @A.J.Uppal: You got it backwards; `len` is implemented in terms of `__len__`; that said, `len` is still the correct solution (it can access `__len__` through optimized C level interfaces, and it's just generally considered more Pythonic to use the special methods implicitly, not explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Simply pythonic way:

```py
from collections import deque 
Q = deque()
if not Q:
   print("Queue is empty")
```

You should know this power of great Python, that each collection becomes `false` if it is empty let it be sets, lists, dictionary, deque etc.

```py
if data_structure:
    print('Data structure is not empty')
else:
   print('Data structure is empty')
```